# OpenGL Quaternion based FPS Camera jiggling

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, frame-rate, glm-math

I am trying to implement a correctly working FPS-like camera on my recent project and decided to use **Quaternions** because that's the way my core engine handles rotation.

So everything is working fine. I handle my input and the camera is moving accordingly but specially when rotating around the global y-Axis (up-Axis) when moving then mouse on the screen-x axis while I try to turn the camera in the same direction (strafing left/right), the object I am looking at (a simple cube) starts jumping a little back and forth.

I really don't know if it's a problem regarding my SDL configuration or my camera code is messed up.

So here's the code for the camera-behaviour:

```
glm::vec2 dm;
if (firstTimeFPS) 
{
    dm = glm::vec2();
    firstTimeFPS = false;
}
else
    dm = pEngine::input->getDeltaMouse();

glm::vec3 translation;


float rotY = dm.x*pEngine::time->deltaTime*0.5;
float rotX = dm.y*pEngine::time->deltaTime*0.5;


m_camera.m_transform.rotate(rotY, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0), true);
m_camera.m_transform.rotate(-rotX, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0), false);

if (pEngine::input->isKeyDown(SDLK_w))
    translation += m_camera.m_transform.getForward();
if (pEngine::input->isKeyDown(SDLK_s))
    translation -= m_camera.m_transform.getForward();
if (pEngine::input->isKeyDown(SDLK_a))
    translation += m_camera.m_transform.getLeft();
if (pEngine::input->isKeyDown(SDLK_d))
    translation -= m_camera.m_transform.getLeft();

glm::normalize(translation);

translation *= pEngine::time->deltaTime * 20;

m_camera.m_transform.translate(translation);
```

And this is the function to calculate my viewMatrix:

```
void Camera::recalculateViewMatrix()
{ 
m_viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(m_transform.position, m_transform.position +   m_transform.getForward(), m_transform.getUp());
}
```

My transform class consists of glm::vec3 for position and scale and one quaternion to represent rotation. The rotation method in the first code-block has a bool parameter checking if its rotating around global(=true) or local axis.

Thank you for taking some time and if more code is requiered or something is not clear yet please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you have your transform code messed up.

But taking a look at your view matrix, makes me think you're not applying it correctly.

Assuming you separated your vectors as follows, your view matrix should be calculated as such.

```
pos = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
dir = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
rot = glm::angleAxis(0.0f, dir);

viewMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(rot) * glm::lookAt(pos, pos + dir, up);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not look like it would fix anything. Instead the movement now is really strange. I guess the problem is due the view not perpendicular to the getLeft() vector..
Like i said the movement went without proplems but this annoying jiggling of the objects doesn't feel right.

Comment: How are you calculating getLeft? Should be `glm::cross(dir, up)`. There may be little perturbations otherwise.

Comment: Currently i am extracting getLeft from the Rotation Quaternion like this: `glm::vec3 Transform::getLeft(float f) { return (glm::normalize(rotation)*glm::vec3(1,0,0)) * f;}` Where float f is a value to scale the direction vector.